# Search same class in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2.17. I have the following in my model:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_next_position

  private

  def set_next_position
    self.position = self.class.where(country_id: country_id).
                    maximum(:position).to_i + 1
  end
end
```

`self` is a `Shop` object. Note the line `self.class.where...` which is equivalent to `Shop.where...`. In this case, I don't know what is the best practice - to use `Shop.where...` or `self.class.where...`? It is code smell to me.

Comment: I would say `self.class.where` is better than `Shop.where` inside the class body. This way, you won't have to change inside, if for some reason you want to rename the class and so on.

Comment: @ollaollu It's called from a callback `before_create`. I need to set the position of the new object before saving.

Comment: noticed that after the comment

Comment: @Babar I concur with your comment too. Please write it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say `self.class.where` is better than `Shop.where` inside the class body. This way, you won't have to change inside, if for some reason you want to rename the class and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I now about is in case of inheritance. When you have:

```
class Base
  def self.example
    42
  end

  def run_example
    Base.example
  end
end

class A < Base
  def self.example
    'not 42'
  end
end

A.new.run_example
=> 42
```

So when don't have inheritance I prefer `Base.example`. In the other case `self.class.example`.